# Javascript to Jquery and JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need this code to work with Jquery / Jquery Mobile, but for some reason it won't work with JQM. Could anybody help me, please? Thanks!

*Javascript Code: It works without JQM*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeOthers(idx, frm) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        if ((frm.elements[i].type == 'select-one')) {
            frm.elements[i].selectedIndex = idx;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*HTML Code: I have multiple forms. There's some select lists inside and I need to set same selected index for all select lists inside working form.*

```
<form name="form1">
    <select name="lst1" size="1" onChange="changeOthers(this.selectedIndex, this.form);">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lst2" size="1" onChange="changeOthers(this.selectedIndex, this.form);">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form name="form2">
    <select name="lst1" size="1" onChange="changeOthers(this.selectedIndex, this.form);">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lst2" size="1" onChange="changeOthers(this.selectedIndex, this.form);">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with jquery mobile, but I do have a bit of experience with jquery ui.  Whenever a control is modified, typically that control needs to be .. 'updated'.

For your code, insert this line in your function, after the index change action:

```
$("select").selectmenu("refresh");
```

See [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh) for more information on the method.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2kzEY/):

```
function changeOthers(idx, frm) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        if (frm.elements[i].type == 'select-one') {
            frm.elements[i].selectedIndex = idx;
            $("select").selectmenu("refresh");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the "refresh" option, but I guess I did something wrong :-) Now it seems to be working!